# Can we define static functions in tclOO?

Tags: tcl

In itcl it was possible to create a proc within a class that allowed

```
namespace eval ns {set ::ns::i 0}

::itcl::class clsTest { 
    set ::ns::i 0 ; 
    proc i {} {
        return [incr ::ns::i]
    }
}

clsTest::i
1
```

Is there some support for this in tclOO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classes are (mostly) ordinary objects in TclOO, so you can do things like creating instance methods on the class itself. That's what `self` in a class-declaration context is for, and it is a powerful technique:

```
oo::class create clsTest {
    self {
        variable i
        method i {} {
            return [incr i]
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you can then do:

```
clsTest i
# ==> 1
clsTest i
# ==> 2
clsTest i
# ==> 3
```

Note that `new` and `create` are *actually* just mostly-ordinary predefined methods (that happen to be implemented in C) but you can add pretty much anything else that you want. And of course `oo::class` inherits from `oo::object`.

You only really need trickery if you are going to make the class-level methods also appear as methods callable on instances. I don't really recommend it, but it's possible with forwarded methods:

```
oo::class create clsTest {
    self { ... }
    # This is actually the simplest thing that will work, provided you don't [rename] the class.
    # Use the fully-qualified name if the class command isn't global.
    forward i  clsTest i
}
```

Comment: Thanks, was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From tcloo wiki at: http://wiki.tcl.tk/21595

```
proc ::oo::define::classmethod {name {args ""} {body ""}} {
    # Create the method on the class if
    # the caller gave arguments and body
    set argc [llength [info level 0]]
    if {$argc == 4} {
        uplevel 1 [list self method $name $args $body]
    } elseif {$argc == 3} {
        return -code error "wrong # args: should be \"[lindex [info level 0] 0] name ?args body?\""
    }

    # Get the name of the current class
    set cls [lindex [info level -1] 1]

    # Get its private “my” command
    set my [info object namespace $cls]::my

    # Make the connection by forwarding
    tailcall forward $name  $my $name
}
```

---

```
oo::class create Foo {
    classmethod boo {x} {
        puts "This is [self]::boo with argument x=$x"
    }
}
```

---

```
Foo create bar
bar boo 42
# --> This is ::Foo::boo with argument x=42
Foo boo 7
# --> This is ::Foo::boo with argument x=7
```